# Why does my 'if' conditional not work unless I put a 'print' statement after the condition?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The beginning of the method in question:

```
def create_axial_features(self):
    # begin executing features
    try:
        roto.command.CommandExecute('TREEVIEW OBJECT SELECT ALL')
        roto.command.CommandExecute('ALIGN COORDINATE_SYSTEM ACTIVE ( "world" )')
        roto.command.CommandExecute('EDIT OBJECT DELETE ()')

        roto.command.CommandExecute(
            'FEATURE PLANE CREATE ("Thrust End of Shaft")')

        if self.var.jobDetails["Thrust Collar"] == "1":
            roto.command.CommandExecute('FEATURE PLANE CREATE ("Inactive Thrust Shoulder")')
            print "done"

        roto.command.CommandExecute(
            'FEATURE PLANE CREATE ("Active Thrust Shoulder")')
        roto.command.CommandExecute(
            'FEATURE CYLINDER CREATE ("TE Bearing Journal")')
```

For some reason, the code under the `if` statement only executes when I add a `print` statement underneath. When I remove the `print`statement, the "Inactive Thrust Shoulder" line fails to execute.
And yes, `self.var.jobDetails["Thrust Collar"]` is always equal to 1, so that's definitely not it.

I have never had a problem like this before, so I am at a loss as to where to start troubleshooting. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is `self.var.jobDetails["Thrust Collar"]` equal to `1` or `'1'`?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the `print` statement causes this. How are you determining that the line before is not being executed? What does that *do*? Could it be that data is sent to stdout but is not yet visible because it is buffered, and the newline sent by the `print` flushes the buffer?

Comment: Try replacing the `print` statement with a call to `sys.stdout.flush()` - if the output then appears, it's "just" a buffering issue. Your premise (that the `print` "makes things work") is extremely unlikely to be correct.

Comment: @holdenweb I think you may be right. It stopped working even with the `print` statement. I replaced the `print` statement with  `sys.stdout.flush()` and moved it above the line I want to be executed. It began working again.

Comment: Great. It would be helpful if you can determine exactly what was happening and why you thought there was an error, and then write your own answer to assist others who may have dug a similar hole for themselves. If you aren't going to do that, maybe you could delete the question, since your problem is solved but the question alone would be of limited value to other readers.

Comment: @NickA You were right. It was equal to `1` when a new job was created, but when a job was loaded, it would load it as `"1"` from a .csv file. That's why it worked sometimes and not others. Before I added the `print` statement, I created a new job in the program, and after I added the `print` statement, I simply reloaded my test job and it worked. Therefore I incorrectly attributed the error to the lack of a `print` statement.

Comment: @RBuntu it's a fairly frequent error to see, if you're unsure what a data type from user input is going to be then its always worth casting both sides of a comparison to the same type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue

It had to do with this line:

`if self.var.jobDetails["Thrust Collar"] == "1":`

When a new job is started, the value `"1"` stored as an integer since it was just inputted by the user. When an old job is loaded however, it loads the value as a string from a saved text file. Therefore, the `if` conditional would only run when it was a loaded job. I falsely attributed it to memory buffering issues since I created the job new during the first test, and simply loaded the job the second test, and in my head, the only thing I had changed in the code itself between the first and second test was adding a `print` statement.